# Google Calendar dashboard

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-calendar-api, reminders

I'm creating a web page dashboard that I will display on a screen in my house for my family to see, the dashboard will have a calendar, weather widget and 2 other widgets: Today's events and reminders from my Google calendars account.

The question is how can I get a feed to display a list of today's events and another list of today's reminders from Google calendar? This is a static page and it will be a read-only page so no events can be added from this page. I went to Google Calendar API but couldn't find anything, most of the documentation there is about creating apps that allows the creation and invitation to events but no current data displayed. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) to display all events related to you.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

Use the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) to test this now.

How the data is presented in your own UI is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be what I'm looking for